# How do I search a file outside the directory of installed module using pkg_resources?

Tags: python, pkg-resources

Suppose:

```
- dir1
  - subdir
    - installed_module
- dir2
  - dbfile
```

This is my folder structure. I want to find `dbfile` and I am in some other directory. How to use `pkg_resources` in python to find the location of the `dbfile` using installed module `installed_module`?

I tried using pkg_resources.resource_filename('installed_module', dbfile) to get some path that isn't what I was expecting.

Comment: If this is new code look at importlib instead https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it using pkg_resources or pkg_util?

Comment: Yes, there is, but you'll need to make an MCVE. The folder structure of your working directory does not tell sufficient information (would need to see the installer / packaging code to see where the installed code goes to - the installed files are the only files that `pkg_resources` knows about).